# tabularray: Wrong numbering in \listoftables with KOMA class

Tags: tabularray

- I use KOMA for a document.
- When I include a table generated with the excellent `tabularray` package, then the numbering in the `\listoftables` and the actual table do not match (the chapter prefix is missing).
- **Question:** How to correct the numbering in `\listoftables`?
- I did not find a related question but I would be surprised if I am the first to notice.

---

```
% Tested on Overleaf with the newest pdfLaTeX version (TeXLive 2021).
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Caption},
  entry = {LoT Caption},
  label = {tab:label};
]{
  colspec = {t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}},
  rowhead = 1,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\toprule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I get 1.1 in my test with your code. `tabularray` release 2021-12-01

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in an older version of `tabularray`? I think overleaf still has version 2021L

Comment: @egreg Thanks! That is good to know. So I "just" need to wait until TeXLive gets updated.

Comment: @marv Yes, maybe, good point. As I wrote in the question `% Tested on Overleaf with the newest pdfLaTeX version (TeXLive 2021).`

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce the issue using the 2021-10-01 release (2021L).

Comment: @egreg Please wait maybe a day before closing. Maybe there is a patch that I can use in the meantime because I cannot switch Overleaf easily.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner OK, retracted vote and provided the patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is fixed in version 2021Q, released 2021-12-01, so it appears you have a previous version.

The following patch seems to fix the problem, but some other things were changed, so this is provided with no warranty. The old version had `\arabic{table}` instead of `\thetable`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DefTblrTemplate { caption-lot } { normal }
  {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__tblr_caption_short_tl { \InsertTblrText { entry } }
    \tl_if_empty:NT \l__tblr_caption_short_tl
      { \tl_set:Nx \l__tblr_caption_short_tl { \InsertTblrText { caption } } }
    \addcontentsline { lot } { table }
      { \protect\numberline { \thetable } { \l__tblr_caption_short_tl } }
  }
\SetTblrTemplate { caption-lot } { normal }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Caption},
  entry = {LoT Caption},
  label = {tab:label};
]{
  colspec = {t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}t{0.20\linewidth}},
  rowhead = 1,
  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
}
\toprule
A & B & C \\
\toprule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\\midrule
a & b & c\\
\bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
 
\end{document}
```

I compiled this using version 2021L and the output is

[image]